# Время на сервере

Tags: centos, время

Сервер CentOS 7
проблема следующая:

```
[root@web ~]# date
Чт июн 29 17:53:23 +07 2017
[root@web ~]# hwclock --systohc --localtime
[root@web ~]# hwclock --utc
Пт 30 июн 2017 00:53:32 -0.484715 секунд
```

как???
когда на самом деле UTC 10:53:32

Comment: [root@web ~]# timedatectl
Local time: Чт 2017-06-29 19:42:41 +07
Universal time: Чт 2017-06-29 12:42:41 UTC
RTC time: Чт 2017-06-29 12:42:41
Time zone: Asia/Krasnoyarsk (+07, +0700)
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
RTC in local TZ: no
DST active: n/a

Comment: [root@web ~]# hwclock --show --utc
Чт 29 июн 2017 19:43:39 -0.094077 секунд
[root@web ~]# hwclock --show
Чт 29 июн 2017 19:43:42 -0.609769 секунд
[root@web ~]# hwclock --show --localtime
Чт 29 июн 2017 12:44:16 -1.000399 секунд

- vsftpd сервер при использовании use_localtime=YES делает UTC+7+7, но проблема не в нем
то есть ставит дату создания файла 02.45.00 следующие сутки